# redefining css overflow?

Tags: css, overflow, redefine

My main div `.container` is set to overflow:hidden; to maintain 100% height, it nests all content divs except for my header and footer. However inside is my sidebar which contains things that need to overflow out and redefining a child div doesn't seem to work. Is there a way around this?

Comment: how about posting some code or details so we could see what you currently tried / did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to either define your parent DIV with `overflow: auto;` or set your child div to be absolutely positioned.